# UPDATE one row in a table from a SELECT statement from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. My tables were created as follows. For a given `device_id`, I'd like to select the record from the temperature table with the max `record_time`, and `UPDATE` the `last_record_time` column in the `devices` tables for that `device_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS devices(
  device_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  device_name varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  last_record_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '1995-10-30 10:30:00'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temperature(
  device_id integer NOT NULL,
  temperature decimal NOT NULL,
  record_time timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT temperature_device_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (device_id)
    REFERENCES devices (device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

I get the max `record_time` from `temperature` table as follow:

```
SELECT MAX(record_time) FROM temperature WHERE device_id=4;
```

This works. How do I pipe the output of the second query into an `UPDATE` statement so that the `last_record_time` in the record in the `devices` table that corresponds to the provided `device_id` is updated. I have read about `INNER JOIN`, but that seems to put together several records. The `device_id` is unique in the `devices` table. So, I need this to `UPDATE` exactly one record every time.

Comment: have you tried any update query  for this ?

Comment: @krishnPatel That's my question. I that I want to `UPDATE`, and I know how to get the value that I want. But, I don't know how to actually write that it out myself. I want to know, how would that `UPDATE` statement actually be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this;

```
update devices set last_record_time = (select max(record_time) from 
temperature where device_id = devices.device_id)
where device_id = 4
```

Comment: `d` and `t` are alias to `devices` and `temperature`?

Comment: update devices set last_record_time = (select max(record_time) from 
temperature where device_id = devices.device_id)
where device_id = 4

You only need to specify the device ID once